# Best way of returning array values without keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, return, flip

I have this array and I want to return the value's as an array from this array (confusing myself here).

```
 array (size=5)
 6 => int 12058
 7 => int 12061
 12 => int 12057
 13 => int 12063
 14 => int 12059
```

The way that I am currently doing the function in question is array_keys(array_flip($above_array)) this does exactly what I want. Is there a built in function or a better way of doing what I want to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$newArray = array_values($array);`

Comment: @mary13123123 Remember to mark the answer you choose as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's an `array_values()` function that returns the values, same as `array_keys` would return the keys.

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $a = array(6 => 12058, 7 => 12061, 12 => 12057, 13 => 12063, 14 => 12059);
php > var_dump(array_values($a));
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(12058)
  [1]=>
  int(12061)
  [2]=>
  int(12057)
  [3]=>
  int(12063)
  [4]=>
  int(12059)
}
```